# Display form within certain time by comparing with current date

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display my form within a certain time.I am comparing the current time with the start and end datetime in MYSQL database. My form doesnt show up even though there's no datetime in the database yet. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$startTimeAuc = mysql_query("SELECT startTime FROM questions WHERE survey_id='1'");
$startTime = mysql_fetch_assoc($startTimeAuc);
$startTime = strtotime($startTime['startTime']);
$endTimeAuc = mysql_query("SELECT endTime FROM questions WHERE survey_id='1'");
$endTime = mysql_fetch_assoc($endTimeAuc);
$endTime = strtotime($endTime['endTime']);


$currentTimeAuc =(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
if( ( $currentTimeAuc >= $startTime && $currentTimeAuc <= $endTime)){
?>

<form name="auctionQuestion" method="post">
------- display----- 
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. You're missing values and wonder why it isnt working? 2. You're comparing timestamps to datetime strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the following code, if $endTime doesn'thave a value, then it can't be greater than or equal to current time. current time can't also be greater than start time if start time doesn't have a value yet... or it will be if startTime = 0 because it holds no value. However there is no evidence here to suggest that.

```
if( ( $currentTimeAuc >= $startTime && $currentTimeAuc <= $endTime)){
```

I would recommend you comment out your SQL and get the PHP right first. Use some static variables and then when you have the script working with statically define variables, hook it up to the database.

What you have sir/ma'am, is an incomplete script :)